# Fetching meeting rooms status into SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-calendar

Is there any way for fetching meeting rooms(Office 365) into SharePoint and show if a room is booked/free and for how long respectively?

Suggestions as to how I'd approach this would really be appreciated.

Comment: Is it achievable or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use Graph API to fetch the outlook meeting events**
**There you can get all the status if meeting is completed or pending**

**API -Get me/events**

Link for more information

[Get outlook meetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)